# html native dropdown - open menu items on enter click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, accessibility

on select enter click, by default form gets submitted on.As per accessibility criteria, if focus is on select element on enter click it should open list items. I want to know is it possible to make accessible dropdown using native select element which will meet accessibility criteria

```
<div class="custom-dropdown">
    <select id="cities" name="select">
       <option value="1">Delhi</option>
       <option value="2">Mumbai</option>
</select>``
</div>
```

I have prevented default submission behaviour.

```
$('.custom-dropdown').keydown(function (event) {
      if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
      }
});
```

I have tried keyup event to trigger click event but its not working

```
$('#cities').keyup(function (e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        $("#cities").trigger("click");
      }
    });
```

Comment: You appear to be complaining that browsers standard UX doesn't match the accessibility criteria you want. There doesn't seem to be a question here.

Comment: I agree its default browser behavior.I just want to know is it possible to make accessable dropdown using native select element which will meet accessibility criteria mentioned in https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/listbox/listbox-collapsible.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're basing your concern on an *example*, not the specification:

> The example listbox on this page implements the following keyboard interface

If you refer to [Keyboard Interaction for the Listbox Design Pattern](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#listbox_kbd_interaction), the *Enter* key is not mentioned.

The example uses *Enter*, because the trigger for the listbox is a Button.

Also, in general, ARIA rules are meant for cases where you cannot use standard elements, according to the [First rule of ARIA use](https://www.w3.org/TR/using-aria/#firstrule)

> If you can use a native HTML element [HTML51] or attribute with the semantics and behavior you require already built in, instead of re-purposing an element and adding an ARIA role, state or property to make it accessible, then do so.

In other words, you shouldn't care about those rules, when you don't implement your own controls.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the only element that will submit a form automatically is a submit button.

```
<input type="submit" value="foo">
```

or

```
<button>foo</button>
```

(the default `type` for a `<button>` element is "submit")

The [`<select>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html53/sec-forms.html#the-select-element) is not defined as submitting a form.  Are you sure your focus is on the <select> when you press <kbd>enter</kbd>?

You should also look at the specs for "[4.10.18.6. Form submission](https://www.w3.org/TR/html53/sec-forms.html#form-control-infrastructure-form-submission)"

Comment: yes, focus is on select element when I pressed enter.Please check this on https://www.accessibilityoz.com/forms/mobile-app-accessibility-audit-request/

Comment: are you saying the audit request page on AccessibilityOz is showing the problem?  if i go to the first <select> on that form, the question "Does the mobile app include a process that needs to be tested?", i can expand the dropdown list using SPACE (on firefox), arrow down to "yes", and hit ENTER to select "yes" and the form is not submitted

Comment: it's just an example.move focus to any select element (ex. "Have you received an accessibility complaint about the mobile app?") using tab keys . then hit enter.Forms gets submitted on enter key press. But if you see accessibility specs for dropdown it states on enter key press it should open list items. Please check keyboard support section on https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/listbox/listbox-collapsible.html

Comment: sorry, i'm not seeing that behavior.  i tried firefox and chrome and pressing enter on any of the selects on the accessibilityoz page does **not** submit the form.

Comment: I am seeing this behavior on chrome Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit).on Firefox its not submitting form after pressing enter key

Comment: i'm using the latest chrome, Version 72.0.3626.119 (Official Build) (64-bit).  pressing ENTER on a select just opens the list (yes/no in this case).  i can then arrow to a choice and press ENTER again to select and the form is **not** submitted.  i'm using firefox 65.0.1 (64-bit) and it works fine too.

Comment: The statement in this answer is wrong, According to [Implicit submission](https://www.w3.org/TR/html53/sec-forms.html#implicit-submission) _Enter_ will submit the form if focus is in a text field. This is even used widely in search fields

Comment: My statement about a button submitting a form is correct.  You are sort of correct in saying that that is not the **only** way to submit a form.  A user agent (browser) **may** support implicit submission but it's not a requirement.  It's strongly encouraged but not a requirement.  So it could be that a button is the only way to submit.  The spec does say that an <input> (not a <select>) might automatically submit **if** there's a default submit button, so lots of conditions on when it would happen.  It says nothing about automatically submitting if a <select> is selected.